# I don't know why this Ruby Fibonacci sequence works

Tags: ruby, fibonacci

I'm writing a program that pushes Fibonacci numbers into an array, using Ruby. The code works, but I can't wrap my head around *why* it works.

This part I understand, it's the Fibonacci equation:

```
fib_array = []

def fib (n)
    return n if n <= 1
    fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
end
```

This is what I don't understand:

```
10.times do |x|
    fib_array << fib(x)
end

print fib_array
```

I wrote this grasping at straws, and it works. I don't understand why. I didn't feed it a number to start at, does Ruby take that to mean 0? Also, how did it know to compound the numbers instead of printing [0, 0, 0...]? I apologize if this is a dunderheaded question, but I'm at loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the bottom piece of code simply calls the `fib` function on `x=0, x=1 ... x=9` and stores it's return value at the end of the array. When `times` is invoked with an iteration variable (x), it begins at 0 and increments on each iteration through the loop. You never fed it a value, however it manages to successfully solve the problem with the iteration variable `x` being passed in as the parameter to `fib`.

Answer (score 2):

The second part of your code says:

"From the instance `10` of the class `Integer`, call the method `times` with the given block" (The method "recive" a block implicitly).

What is a block? A small piece of code between `{braces}` or a `do-end` (like you did).

The method `times` is called, "iterator". And it will `yield` 0,1,2,..,9 (in your case). An iterator and the yield statement are always together. Think that `yield` is like `return` with memory, when you look for more information.

So, your code could be re-writing like:

```
10.times { |x| fib_array << fib(x) }
```

And it will call, the block you pass, on every `yield` that the method `times`
does. Calling the method `<<` (append) to the result of `fib(x)` on your array.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

```
def fib (n)
  return n if n <= 1
  fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
end
```

which you understand.  First let's see what are the first 5 Fibonacci numbers::

```
fib_array = []
5.times do |x| 
  fib_array << fib(x)
end
fib_array
  #=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Now let's break this down and see what happening. First look at the docs for the method `times`. To find them, we need to know what class or module the method is from, because that's how the docs are organized. As `5.class #=> Fixnum`, we might look at the docs for [Fixnum](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html).  Hmmm. `times` is not there. Evidentally, it was inherited from another class. Let's check:

```
Fixnum.ancestors
  #=> [Fixnum, Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

`Integer` includes `Fixnum` and `BigNum`, `Numeric` includes `Integer` and `Float`. `(3.14).times` doesn't make sense, so it appears `times` is defined in `Integer`, and so it is: [Integer#times](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times). By defining it there, it is inherited by both `Fixnum` and `Bignum`.

Here's a direct way to determine where the method came from:

```
5.method(:times).owner #=> Integer
```

It's not important understand this now, but you'll find it handy as you gain experience with Ruby.

OK, the docs say that `times` return a value if given a block, or an enumerator if not. Let's forget about the block a moment and look at the enumerator that is returned:

```
enum = 5.times         #=> #<Enumerator: 5:times>
```

The method [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) passes the elements of the enumerator `enum` to its block:

```
do |x| 
  fib_array << fib(x)
end
```

assigning them to the block variable `x`. To see the contents of the enumerator, convert it to an array:

```
enum.to_a           #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The result is:

```
fib_array = []
enum.each do |x| 
   fib_array << fib(x)
end
fib_array
  #=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

which of course is the same result that we obtained previously. Now let's see what's happening step-by-by, by using the method [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to extract each element of the enumerator:

```
x = enum.next       #=> 0 
fib(x)              #=> 0 
fib_array << fib(x) #=> [0] 

x = enum.next       #=> 1 
fib(x)              #=> 1 
fib_array << fib(x) #=> [0, 1] 

x = enum.next       #=> 2 
fib(x)              #=> 1 
fib_array << fib(x) #=> [0, 1, 1] 

x = enum.next       #=> 3 
fib(x)              #=> 2 
fib_array << fib(x) #=> [0, 1, 1, 2] 

x = enum.next       #=> 4 
fib(x)              #=> 3 
fib_array << fib(x) #=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3] 

print fib_array     # [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

That's all there is to it.